# Can `rm` be an alternative to `parity db kill`

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, synchronization

In my configuration, I have specified base-path as follows:

```
[parity]
chain = "chain-spec.json"
base_path = "./parityData"
```

Can I remove chain data by removing database files in parity?

```
rm -rf ./parityData/cache ./parityData/chains
```

#### My results:

After removal of data directories, when I restart parity, it does not sync from beginning, it resumes from last synced point? Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths. Try

```
[parity]
chain = "~/chain-spec.json"
base_path = "~/parityData"
```

And

```
rm -rf ~/parityData/cache ~/parityData/chains
```

But be aware that removing `chains/` removes *all* chains you have plus a configuration of your nodes and your networking key.